# Prevent Grphviz arrow edge from crossing neighbour node

Tags: graphviz

I've created the following graphviz graph, represented a linked list with cycles:

```
igraph foo {
    rankdir=LR;
    node [shape=record];
    a [label="{ <data> 12 | <ref>  }", width=1.2]
    b [label="{ <data> 99 | <ref>  }"];
    c [label="{ <data> 37 | <ref>  }"];
    a:ref:c -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false, arrowsize=1.2];
    b:ref:c -> c:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    c:ref:c -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
}
```

Unfortunately, the arrow from `c:ref` to `b:data` crosses node `c`:

[image]

How do I force the edge to go around the nodes without crossing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a simple and fully satisfying answer, but changing the compass point may help.

```
digraph foo {
    rankdir=LR;
    node [shape=record];
    a [label="{ <data> 12 | <ref>  }", width=1.2]
    b [label="{ <data> 99 | <ref>  }"];
    c [label="{ <data> 37 | <ref>  }"];
    a:ref:c -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false, arrowsize=1.2];
    b:ref:c -> c:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    c:ref:s -> b:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
}
```

[image: changed compass point]

Answer (score 1):

You can run `"dot -Tsvg"` for your dot file and after that open `svg` file with `ms visio` for example and do something like that [image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, That's an interesting idea, but I'm looking for a graphviz solution. I don't like the idea of manually editing every linked list after compiling it.